# uncaught error in Angular when using $locationProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the path. So I have:

```
use strict';

angular.module('wixApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'wix'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).requireBase(false);
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

However, when I run this, I get uncaught error: `$[injector:modulrr]`

This only happens when I add `$locationProvider` in `.config`

here is the error in console:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=wixApp&p1=TypeErro…2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83)
Object

Comment: I'm using Angular's version 1.4.12

Comment: add full error report

Comment: how do i add a full error report for a chrome browser?

Comment: error added to the thread

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the module could not be instantiated which is mostly caused by some invalid module dependencies. Did you forget to add the angular-route javascript file to your build process (or as script tag in the index.html)?

For a correct setup please refer to the docs here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ngRoute

If you are using the non-minified version of angular during development, you will also get some better readable error messages.

Comment: No. I double-checked. <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/app.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

Comment: all I want to do is to get a path of the URL. For that I need to configure $locationProvider.

Comment: I used a non-min version and I got this: angular.js:4505 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module wixApp due to:
TypeError: $locationProvider.html5Mode(...).hashPrefix(...).requireBase is not a function But I don't know what I can do as wixApp is not mine.

Comment: In your first comment, you placed your scripts before the angular-route.js file. Try changing this order so that your code is run after angular-route has registered.

Comment: tried. this is what i got. Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Okay. I re-read your error message and it says that requireBase is not a function, which is correct. You can pass it as a property of an object instead of a boolean value for the html5Mode. See https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider. Hope this solves your problem...

Comment: thank you very much. this seems to have worked:      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
      });